# R: Optimizing with Torch - optimizer$step() throws up this error

Tags: r, optimization, torch

Using Torch in R to create a simple neural network, with optim_adam as the optimizer. While trying to update the model parameters, I get the following error on running optimizer$step() - "Error in param$state[["exp_avg"]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

What could be the reason?

I get the error on running this code (https://blogs.rstudio.com/ai/posts/2020-10-09-torch-optim/) as well.

Code:

```
d_in <- 3
d_out <- 1
n <- 100


# create random data
x <- torch_randn(n, d_in)
y <- x[, 1, NULL] * 0.2 - x[, 2, NULL] * 1.3 - x[, 3, NULL] * 0.5 + torch_randn(n, 1)

d_hidden <- 32

model <- nn_sequential(
  nn_linear(d_in, d_hidden),
  nn_relu(),
  nn_linear(d_hidden, d_out)
)

learning_rate <- 0.08

optimizer <- optim_adam(model$parameters, lr = learning_rate)

### training loop --------------------------------------------------------------

for (t in 1:200) {
  
 
  y_pred <- model(x)
  
  loss <- nnf_mse_loss(y_pred, y, reduction = "sum")
  
  optimizer$zero_grad()
  loss$backward()
  
  optimizer$step()
}
```